# Custom mat calendar header

Tags: angular, angular-material, calendar

I am expecting the mat calendar header as customised one like in the below screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only create a custom header like the [example of the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-calendar-header)

You can use with a mat-calendar like

```
  <mat-calendar [headerComponent]="exampleHeader" [(selected)]="date">
  </mat-calendar>
```

See the forked stackblitz of the example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-td2g2v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-custom-header-example.html)

Comment: im guessing based on the stackblitz you couldnt get <mat-icon> to work within the template either? thats the issue i am running into where within the template code for the header it throws an error that it cant find <mat-icon> but if i throw the same code in the html it works there which is confusing idk where i am missing an import for maticonmodule

Comment: @chitgoks, if you want "remove" the name of the month inside the calendar, you can add in styles.css:`.custom .mat-calendar-body-label{  visibility: hidden;}` and use in .html: `<mat-calendar class="custom"...>`

Comment: @Eliseo i used opacity: 0 instead

Comment: @dEv93 I can make mat-icon work inside th day cell.  did you add class="material-icons"? my problem with it is that i cannot use [matTooltip] since in angular it renders directives inside innerHTML useless. i cant find a workaround yet.

Answer (score 0):

Above stackblitz doesn't show how to properly format the calendar header. If you want the header to display in 'MMMM YYYY' format. Change periodLabel() to below:

```
  get periodLabel() {
    return this._dateAdapter.format(this._calendar.activeDate, this._dateFormats.display.monthYearA11yLabel);
  }
```